# Which permission is required to edit Record Type field?

Tags: record-type

Which permission is required to edit Record Type field on a object?

Answer (score 4):

You need permission to the various record types as well as 'edit' permission on the object.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.But I've checked that the Profile has got edit permission on Object and Record Type also has edit option for same profile.Then what are the other ways to restrict the Record type to make non-editable to particular profile or user?

Answer (score 0):

For me, with the Sys Admin profile, I had to assign all of the records individually instead of assigning the master record type.